# Retrieving Digital Certificate of website in my asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

How can I get the certificate from another website like Facebook, Google etc. using `ASP.NET` and check validity of certificate?

Comment: Refer this link .It may help [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315588) [link 2](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/clientcertificatemappingauthentication)

Comment: I think you'd better provide more information about what you want to do and how your application is structured.

Comment: I am developing an application in asp.net in which I am providing the option to user like check certificate of the website they are going to visit. For that I have to get the certificate first and then insert it in the database.